# JS Hint error: for-loop local variable is already defined

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, jshint

I am doing multi-pass operations on a 2D array. Basically like this:

```
function heightMap() {
  var seedList = [],
      tileList = [];
  //forloop filling tileList

  while(seedList.length<20) {
      var tile = tileList[randomX][randomY];
      //do stuff to tile
      seedList.push(tile);
  }
  for(var x in tileList) {
    for(var y in tileList {
      var tile = tileList[x][y];
      //do stuff to tile
    }
  }
}
```

JS-Hint says tile is already defined under the for loop. What? Is that right? This doesn't fit with my understanding of scope. IDK if it's worth noting, but everything executes fine.

Comment: Javascript has function scope, not block scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript only has function scope. Both of your loops are within the same function, therefore they are in the same scope, so the `tile` in your for loop is in the same as the one in your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [ES6 let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement in place of *`var`*, you can define variables with block scope. For instance Node.js version 4 and above supports the use of the let statement.